# fpdf AddCol height without using MultiCell

Tags: php, height, pdf-generation, fpdf

I tried searching everywhere to set height of table cell when data has more than one sting while extracting from database. But I'm getting result for only `MultiCell` which I cant implement in my `fpdf-test.php`.

I'm searching to set height when I use `AddCol` in my `fpdf` file. I want the cell to auto adjust height when there is more number of strings in that particular cell. Below is my code  of my `fpdf` page.

```
<?php

require('mysql_table.php');
class PDF extends PDF_MySQL_Table
{
mysql_connect('localhost','root','1234');
mysql_select_db('db');


$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->AddCol('ticket_id',45,'Ticket ID','L');
$pdf->AddCol('passengers_name',50,'Name','L');
$pdf->AddCol('no_of_seats',15,'Seats','L');
$pdf->AddCol('travel_date',35,'Journey Date','L');
$pdf->AddCol('total',25,'Total Amt','R');
$prop=array('HeaderColor'=>array(255,150,10),
        'color1'=>array(210,245,255),
        'color2'=>array(255,255,210),
        'padding'=>5);


$pdf->Table('SELECT * FROM travels_booking WHERE paymentFlag=1 and travel_date BETWEEN "'.$_POST["fromdate"].'" AND "'.$_POST["todate"].'"',$prop);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Here `passengers name` contains more than one string. While extracting from db it has to adjust its height like same in `MultiCell`. Is there any other method to adjust its height without using `Multicell` method when I use `AddCol` method in `fpdf`?

Comment: try use `writeHTML`